# Laravel react Error 500 when login Using Auth

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, database, laravel-sanctum

I've been trying to solve this problem for several days but can't figure out the solution.
Could you help me please?
Laravel UserController code:

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $request->validate(
            [
                'email'    => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]
        );
        if (Auth::guard()->attempt([['email' => $request->input('email')], ['password' => $request->input('password')]])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'));
            if($user != null){
                $user->isLogin = true;
                $user->save();
                return response()->json(['id'=>$user->id], 200);
            }
            return response()->json(['message'=>'User not found'],404);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid credentials'],400);
     }
```

React api fetch with axios:

```
const logIn=(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/login', {
        email: email,
        password:password
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.status==200){
          console.log(response.data)
          dispatch(login(response.data.id))
        }
    }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error.message)
    })
  }
```

Laravel login in routs:

```
Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
```

Laravel log:

[2022-08-10 11:36:34] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = id) limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = id) limit 1) at C:\xampp\htdocs\socialmedia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:742)

Comment: `$user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'));` is incomplete, you forgot the `->first()`, so `$user` is a QueryBuilder object, not a single model result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing multidimensional array in where condition

Can you try  changing this lines

```
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 
       'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
//here we are getting the first value
       User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first()
```

You can see this doc for more info related to login https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Same problem after that tooo.
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (`0` = id) limit 1)",

Comment: can you please add ```die("reached");``` inside the if condition to debug

Comment: Also can try the updated code